# Filling fields forms in backend from two different tables

Tags: backend, dataflow, forms

Currently, we have several forms that allow to edit/delete information, each one loading the data from one particular table. But what I want is to be able to load on the `Form.php` information from different tables.

On the code below there is a field name **imagefilename**. This field belongs to another table that is linked with a foreign key to the one I'm loading on the first `if` sentence on the line `$data = Mage:: registry('banners_data')->getdata();` that was saved on the previous page at user click.

So I have the main ID and can search on the images table the needed data. But no matter how I try, it does not correctly load the information I need. I tried searching for samples but no luck or maybe I'm just not using the correct terms.

Here is a part of my _prepareForm function, without any code to load the image table as it was triggering some errors.

```
    protected function _prepareForm() {
        if (Mage::registry('banners_data')->getdata())  {
            $data = Mage::registry('banners_data')->getdata();
        }
        elseif (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')) {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getdata();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getdata(null);
        }
        else {
            $data = array();
        }

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array('id' => 'edit_form',
                    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', $params),
                    'method' => 'post',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ));

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('banners_form', 
            array('legend' =>Mage::helper('banners')->__('Campaign details page')));

        $fieldset->addField('banner_name', 'text',
            array(  'label'     => Mage::helper('banners')->__('Name'),
                    'class'     => 'required-entry',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'name'      => 'banner_name',
                    'note'      => Mage::helper('banners')->__('campaign name'),
                    'tabindex' => 1
    ));
.....
        $fieldset->addField('imagefilename', 'file',
            array(  'label'   => Mage::helper('banners')->__('Image to upload'),
                    'name'    => 'imagefilename',
                    'disabled'=> false,
                    'note'    => Mage::helper('banners')->__('Image you want to upload'),
                    'readonly'=> true,
                    'tabindex'=> 10
.....
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you fill the fields? (Typically `$form->setValues()`)

Comment: What you save in Mage::registry() is only available while the current page is loaded. You can't access the registry from the 'previous page'. You could try instead saving it to the user session.

Comment: @RickKuipers, I will, back in the office tomorrow morning. Fooman, I'm currently saving the data on user click on the page where I show the grid with all the rows. And all the fields on the form.php are filled without problems on the _prepareForm function I posted on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are certain, that you have imagefilename ID in $data, then load image file name from DB, and add it to $data with 'imagefilename' then when you do setValues, it should be picked up.
If it is not too much overhead, add a JOIN to initial data loading part and fetch image file name there. Will save you one more trip to database.

Comment: That is what I was thinking off. But then the collection where I save all the values should be different. And therefore the line `Mage::registry('banners_data')->getdata();` should change, I must use a different collection. Will give it a try.

Comment: As far as I know when you save, model resource saves only valid data. I mean I have some models where I need to have some additional things, like you do, and saving collection did not produce errors.See Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_prepareDataForTable